# Why can't I install TortoiseGit 1.6.3.0 on Windows 7?

Tags: git, windows-7, tortoisegit

My laptop is running Windows 7 Home Basic.

Every time I try to install TortoiseGit 1.6.3.0, it quits about 3/4 of the way through with the message:

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly component 
>        {89EDD3A9-944B-3257-8484-D6EB6A00DDF5}. 
>      HRESULT: 0x800736FD

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem on a newly installed Windows 7. After installing *Service Pack 1* via the updates it got installed.

This error is most probably because of the lack of a Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure it will fix your problem, but a lot of searches for error 0x800736FD keep referring back to the need to update or install a redistributable run-time package. You could try installing it - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the MSI installer executable, as mentioned in [this technote](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/error/1935.htm).

> A 1935 error is one of the most common problems that can prevent a user from being able to install the .NET Framework, J# redistributable package, Visual Studio or any other application that uses the Windows Installer MSIAssembly and MSIAssemblyName tables to install assemblies. Troubleshooting steps are described in [Aaron Stebner's WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2004/11/10/255346.aspx)

So check your .Net framework current setting/version, and see the WebLog for full diagnostics and workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Start the Windows Modules Installer service in services.msc.

TortoiseGit tries to install either a .NET Framework or a Visual C++ redistributable, and the aforementioned service is needed for the install. I do not know any specifics, but it works here.

Comment: TortoiseGit is built on VC++ 2008, which requires VC++ 9.0 redistributable. It does not need .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Installation of Visual C++ redistibutable has not helped me.

What helped me is running of Windows6.1-KB947821-v25-x64.msu.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3132

The tool fixed some mistakes in the registry and I was able to install tortoise.

The problem is quite common. Hope this helps.